# PowerBI Embed Token using NodeJS unable to Resolve Token Authorization URL

Tags: node.js, access-token, powerbi-embedded

What i am trying to achieve is to embed existing PowerBI report to my Angular Application. To get PowerBI Embed Token, I am using the code as shared in this URL for NODEJS [https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/NodeJS].

When I run via my local machine as API and call via Angular, it throws this error as follow:
***error: 'ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/##TENANTID##/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.](https://login.microsoftonline.com/##TENANTID##/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration%27.)***
This is the same when I run via AWS EC2 with our internal corporate Proxy.

However if I run EC2 with Elastic IP (without corporates proxy) it works all fine. I have limitation and must run with Corporate Proxy.

**My real concern here is we have the same CODE in PYTHON (same GITHUB [link](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/Python)) that works in all environment and with corporate proxy and no trouble to get token.**

I am seeking help with NODEJS and point out how it differ in behavior with Python code. How i can able to have this code run with internal corporate Proxy since I can't use Direct Elastic IP.

Note: I used the code as-is from GITHUB and added only config details as it require.

Comment: Could you provide for which scenario you're embedding ( for organisation / for customers) and which authentication method (Masteruser / service principal)

Comment: I am using "For customers" and authentication method as "Service Principal"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Venki, Refer to my repo, and lmk if this approach works for you and if you face any issues while implementing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For service principal authentication, we need to authenticate using client Secret. MSAL Angular currently doesn't support Confidential Client applications.

So, we need to use Backend capable of holding secret and to get the Embed token, one workaround I tried is using the Azure Function App as implemented in my [GitHub](https://github.com/KotanaSai21/powerbi-embedded-React-demo) Repo.
Once You get the Function URL, you can embed the report in any language by fetching the details from the URL.

In my repo, embedded the report using `powerbi-client-react`.
You can implement the same and embed the report using `powerbi-client-angular`.

Comment: Thanks @kotana Sai, I will refer & follow the GitHub repo and will confirm you back here. However I was using MSAL Node and MSAL Common which actually performing Confidential Client applications method. Only problem is it works without Organization firewall however if use PYTHON MSAL it works fine even in Organization firewall which is strange behavior.

Comment: Part of the issue I able to handle with this example, there are few other issue but I feel that should be fine as I progress more. Thanks @Kotana Sai